# Powerpoint 2007 Chart find Datalabel Position

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint, com-interop

I have a Problem: I am using Interop to create a chart in Powerpoint and this works well. But I have a problem: I need to get the exact position of the dataseries datalabels to draw some shapes. But how to get the damned position?
The DataLabel has left and top values, but they seem to be invalid, e.g.: if i draw something on that position, it appears way of. Is there some kind of transformation, that I have to do?

My code looks like this:
Imports pptNS = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint

```
for i = 1 to Targetchart.Seriescollection.count

    Dim DtL = DirectCast(TargetChart.SeriesCollection(i).datalabels, pptNS.DataLabels)
    For x = 1 To DtL.count
         Dim   DTS = DirectCast(DTL.Item(DTLItem), pptNS.DataLabel)
         Dim Left =dts.left 'seems to be wrong?
    next
 next
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: The Topposition will be:
TopPos = DTS.Top + TargetChart.ChartArea.Top + TargetShape.Top + 1.5
Dim LeftPos = DTS.Left + TargetChart.ChartArea.Left + TargetShape.Left

1.5. added for the Topposition because there was a little gap...